# how to set background color to nav brand?

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gtBm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaonY.png)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " style="background-color:white;   box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);padding: 0 1rem">
    <a class="navbar-brand pt-0 pb-0" href="#" style="background-color:red;>
        <img id="logo" class="d-inline-block mr-1" alt="Logo" src="~/images/masycoda-solutions.png">

        <span></span>
    </a>




    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="background-color:white">


        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

        {




        <ul class="navbar-nav " style="color: rgb(22,53,71); background-color:white">




            <li class="nav-item active  " style="background-color:navy">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/" style="padding:1rem 1rem">
                    <div class="pl-5 pr-5 ml-4 mr-4">
                        <img src="/img/house.png" class=" ">Home <span class="sr-only ">(current)</span>

                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Dashboard" style="padding:1rem 1rem">
                
                    <div class="pl-5 pr-5 ml-4 mr-4">
                        <img src="/img/house.png" class=" "> Dashboard 

                    </div>
                
               </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/Visitor/VisitorAnalysis" style="padding:1rem 1rem">
                    <div class="pl-5 pr-5 ml-4 mr-4">
                        <img src="~/img/pie-chart.png" />Visitors Analysis
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown pl-5 pr-5 ml-3 mr-3 ">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color:rgb(22,53,71);padding:1rem 1rem">
                    Users
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="color:rgb(22,53,71)">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users">Users List</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users/Create">User Create</a>

                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active   ">

                <img src="/images/Laura_Bush_portrait.jpg" class=" rounded-circle" style="width:26px;height:26px;">
                @User.FindFirst("name").Value<br>
                <a href="/AzureAD/Account/SignOut" style="margin-left:4%;">Sign out</a>


            </li>

        </ul>
           
        }

        else
        {
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="visibility:hidden;">




                <li class="nav-item active pl-5 pr-5 ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active pl-5 pr-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Home/Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active pl-5 pr-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/Visitor/VisitorAnalysis">Visitors Analysis</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown pl-5 pr-5 ">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Users
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users">Users List</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Users/Create">User Create</a>

                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" >Sign in</a>

        }



    </div>
</nav>
```

In first image , we can see i have given background color to  nav brand to red.  But there is space is there which is not fill by red color , why?  i want to fill that color by red.
how to give red color to that space  which is shown in nav brand

Comment: change your nav style color white to red

Comment: can you check the generated html (by clicking the logo and then 'inspect element' in browser console)? Also you can share the generated html for us to understand better.

Comment: Whether there have some other css styles? I have checked your CSS style, you are setting  the `ul` background color to white  and setting  the first `li` element background color to `navy`, after adding background color for other `li` element, the output [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyqfl.png), it doesn't contain space between the `li` elements on my side.So perhaps there have other CSS styles, can you create a simple sample to reproduce it. Second, if you want to set the Space background color, you could change the `ul` element's background color to "Red" .

Answer (score 0):

Your other items in the `navbar` are taller than the `navbar-brand`. That's why there are gaps there.

There are couple ways to do it. One way is to set the `navbar` background to red, instead of white. That will do the trick because `navbar-brand` has transparent background, and `navbar-collapse` has white background:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light " 
     style="background-color:red;
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/q1sfh3wt/9/

What a horrible code to read with all those inline styles I must say...